# how to execute POST and what to return from API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm using c# .net 4.5 to create an API controller that my web app will connect to.  This controller then POSTs data to another API.

So I have my service class:

```
public class PlayerServiceConnector()
{
    private Uri baseUri;
    private String UserName;
    private String Password;

    private string Name;
    private string CharacterRace;
    private string CharacterClass;
    private string AutoSave;
}

public PlayerServiceConnector()
{
    baseUri = new Uri("http://system/dev/API/characterGen");
    UserName = "Joe";
    Password = "12345";

    //just for testing 
    Name = "Mighty Man";
    CharacterRace = "Human";
    CharacterClass = "Warrior";
    AutoSave = true;

    var path = baseUri + "/newCharacter";

    // POST new character data to 3rd party character generating API
    using (var wb = new WebClient())
    {
        wb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        wb.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);

        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["Name"] = Name;
        data["CharacterRace"] = CharacterRace;
        data["CharacterClass"] = CharacterClass;
        data["AutoSave"] = AutoSave.ToString();

        var response = wb.UploadValues(path, "POST", data);

    }
}
```

And I have my .NET ApiController (System.Web.Http):

```
    [Route("api/CharacterGeneration/createNew")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostNewCharacter([FromBody] string value)
    {
        //create new instance of PlayerServiceConnector
        var player = new PlayerServiceConnector();

        //not sure what to do here...
    //how do I get the WebClient part to POST in PlayerServiceConnector?
        //what do I return?

        return NoContent();
    }
```

My issue/question is, when I point my browser to "api/CharacterGeneration/createNew", how do I make sure that the data is POSTed and what do I return to the client?  That is where I am getting stumped and confused.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend doing some research into RestSharp (or similar).  It is very useful for this kind of thing.  http://restsharp.org/

Answer (score 2):

```
    [Route("api/CharacterGeneration")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddNewCharacter([FromBody] Character character)
    {
        if (character == null)
           return BadRequest();

        // put your code for adding the new character here
        // either from your repository or db context

        // return response of 201 if you created the resource successfully
        // typically return this with a uri to the new resource
        return Created("new location", characterYouCreated);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

example of code returnign a list of string:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostNewCharacter([FromBody] string value)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("something");
    list.Add("something else");
    return Json(list);
}
```

running on the browser, will print the string in a Json structure

running from your connector will return the json structure where you can parse to your proxy class.

if you want a framework to parse Json use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json   or find newtonsoft on NuGet inside Visual Studio. Everybody alive I know use newtonsoft for Json

Comment: I get confused with the 'return' part because I am posting data to the API for the system to process...what do I do with the return Json list?  Thanks!

Comment: @999cm999 Where are you posting the data to the API at? Where are you calling the `createNew` method?

Comment: @999cm999 you will Deserialize using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject from the framework I sent you

Comment: @ThePoet but how does this use the code I have in my PlayerServiceConnector() method?  That's where the meat of all my functionality is that interacts with the 3rd party API.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the return part of your question, you could point to the data you posted.

```
return Redirect(new Uri(url), HttpStatusCode.Created);
```

Where url will be the url for the Get route to obtain the data you just posted.

```
var url = Url.Link("Name of your Get route", new object());
```

Your object will be different according to your get route's parameter requirements.